# How to split row in multiple rows and add new column also in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to split row into multiple rows but I need to add one more column when the split will happen. Can you please help me how to do this?

Example:

```
df1:

    rule_id    priority_order    comb_fld_order   
    R162       2.3               1
    R162       2.3.1             1
    R162       2.6               2
    R162       2.6.1             2
    R162       3.0.4             3.2,3.1,3
```

Expected Output:

```
df2:

rule_id    priority_order    comb_fld_order   comb_fld_order_1
R162       2.3               1                 
R162       2.3.1             1                 
R162       2.6               2                 
R162       2.6.1             2                 
R162       3.0.4             3.2              dummy
R162       3.0.4             3.1              dummy
R162       3.0.4             3                dummy
```

For splitting i am using below code but I don't know how to add extra column.

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['rule_id', 'priority_order']).apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',').explode()).reset_index())
```

Comment: if ```priority_order``` is unique, then u can apply group by on tat and take the values whose count is greater than 1 mark as dummy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the lambdas function. You can just explode and call the column name:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'rule_id': ['R162', 'R162', 'R162', 'R162', 'R162'],
    'priority_order': ['2.3', '2.3.1', '2.6', '2.6.1', '3.0.4'],
    'comb_fld_order': ['1', '1', '2', '2', ('3.2', '3.1', '3')]
})

df2 = df1.set_index(['rule_id', 'priority_order']).explode('comb_fld_order')


rule_id priority_order comb_fld_order       
R162    2.3            1
        2.3.1          1
        2.6            2
        2.6.1          2
        3.0.4          3.2
        3.0.4          3.1
        3.0.4          3
```

EDIT:

To address your 2nd requirement, you can do something like this:

```
exploded = df2.groupby('priority_order').count().to_dict()['comb_fld_order']
df2['was_exploded'] = df2.apply(lambda x: 'exploded' if int(exploded[x.name[1]]) > 1 else '', axis=1).values
```

It's not pretty, and I'm certain there's a more concise way, but the idea is that you perform a groupby on the original dataframe and take the values associated with each 'priority_order'. Then you go through your newly constructed dataframe and access the 2nd level of the multi-index to pass that as a key into a dictionary of counts associated with the 'priority_order' values.

`x.name[1]` for a lambdas function accesses the 2nd level of the index associated with the row value of x. Useful little feature that one.

Comment: but how can add that new column at the same time of splitting?

Comment: Is it possible after splitting can we add new column and fill data based on some condition?

Comment: Try out my solution and let me know if it suits. As sushanth points out, for this to work, your priority order must be unique and matched with the column